# Magento mini-cart getSummaryCount inaccurate after removing from cart

Tags: magento-1.9, module, cart, shopping-cart, mini-cart

I have a function that removes all of a product from the cart.

```
public function removeFromCartByProductIdAction()
{
    $productIdToRemove = $this->getRequest()->getParam('productIdToRemove');
    $cartHelper = Mage::helper('checkout/cart');
    $items = $cartHelper->getCart()->getItems();
    foreach ($items as $item) {
        if ($item->getProduct()->getId() == $productIdToRemove) {
            $itemId = $item->getItemId();
            $cartHelper->getCart()->removeItem($itemId)->save();
        }
    }
}
```

If I had 4 of the product in the cart, it will remove all 4 from the cart. But the function `getSummaryCount` provided by Magento `Mage/Checkout/Block/Cart/Minicart.php` will return 3. This persists until  I visit the cart page, after which it will return the correct amount  of 0.

I use the result of `getSummaryCount` to preview how many items are in the cart on my cart icon. How can I ensure it gets the correct summary count after I run my function?

Answer (score 0):

I did not find the root cause, but was able to fix it with a workaround by going into my theme, finding the mini_cart.phtml file, and making this change.

```
<?php $_cartQty = $this->getSummaryCount() ?>
<?php $_items = $this->getRecentItems(); ?>
```

To

```
<?php $_items = $this->getRecentItems(); ?>  
<?php $_cartQty = count($_items); ?>
```